# Trying to cast an output field in Google Big Query as a date

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my standard Google Big Query:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT concat ( safe_cast(fullVisitorID as string), 
safe_cast(visitNumber as string))  as FVID,  /* WORKS */ 



 FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", 
 TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)) as 
 visitStartTimePST,   /* WORKS */ 

 (select value from unnest(h.customDimensions) where index = 7)    as 
     CheckIn,  /* WORKS BUT IS IN FORMAT e.g. 1/1/2017 */ 

[... rest of query deleted for readability ]
```

Here is my issue.  I want the CheckIn to be a date type, so I can do date arithmetic comparing the visitStartTimePST to the CheckIn date (number of days delta).  My various Cast and Format attempts have failed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the CheckIn to be a date type

Below example should help you

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', '1/1/2017')
```

so you might do as

```
...
(select PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', value) from unnest(h.customDimensions) where index = 7)    as 
 CheckIn, 
...
```

note: you might need to switch `'%d/%m/%Y'` to `'%m/%d/%Y'` depends on your locality for `'1/1/2017'`

Comment: (select PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', value) from unnest(h.customDimensions) where index = 7)    as 
 CheckIn,              worked